# Cannot use ngFor directive when using third library element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I'm working on Angular application that use an UMD library for user interface.
The problem that i'm facing is that i cannot use ngFor directive on an element from the library
for exemple:

```
<lib-select>
<lib-option *ngFor="let user from users">---</lib-option>
</lib-select>
```

The above code display an empty select, whereas the bellow doesn't.

```
<select>
<option *ngFor="let user from users">---</option>
<select>
```

How can i handle it ?

Thank you for help!

Best regards.

Comment: please elaborate more what are you trying to do

Comment: without knowing lib-option we can only guess, but I would try and place the *ngFor on a <ng-template> to wrap the lib-option. check this for syntax: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#structural-directive-shorthand

Comment: I have tried to wrap it with ng-template but it is the same issue

Comment: @debugger i want just to use pre-developed component with ngFor loop because it was already styled and conform to the user interface specifications

Answer (score 0):

I'm believe that your ngFor syntax was wrong, let try use `*ngFor="let user of users"` or `*ngForOf="let user of users"`.